# tags = Tag.objects.all() выдаёт ошибку: NameError: name 'Tag' is not defined

Tags: python, django

Выдаёт ошибку

> NameError: name 'Tag' is not defined

у файла views.py на 13 строке.

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import Post

    def posts_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})

    def post_detail(request, slug):
        post = Post.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context={'post': post})

    def tags_list(request):
        tags = Tag.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/tags_list.html', context={'tags': tags})
```

models.py:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.shortcuts import reverse

    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
        body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
        date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.title)


    class Tag(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

urls.py:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),
        path('post/<str:slug>/', post_detail, name='post_detail_url'),
        path('tags/', tags_list, name='tags_list_url')
    ]
```

Comment: На второй строке views.py добавьте Tag после Post через запятую.

Comment: Заработало, благодарю.

Comment: @avtomato, напишите ваш комментарий как ответ, чтобы получить за него баллы.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Добавьте в **views.py**:

```
from .models import Post, Tag
```